# My package gives "ModuleNotFoundError" when importing it on CodeSandBox

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I published an npm package today and wanted to try it on CodeSandBox. It works if I `npm install package-name` in a local machine but importing same dependency on a CodeSandBox projects gives this error:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "version": "1.0.20",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,spec.js,test.js,__snapshots__",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4"
  }
}
```

My compiled files have these kind of imports at top:

```
import _defineProperty from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty";
import _objectSpread from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2";
import _slicedToArray from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/slicedToArray";
```

I followed [this](https://thicolares.com/2019/02/24/creating-a-react-package-and-publishing-it-on-npm-explained.html) tutorial. After I run `npm run build`, a `dist` folder creates in the main directory. Then I `npm publish`. I did try `npm install package-name` on a local machine and it works but as I said it does not work on CodeSandBox.

Comment: A link to your Code sand box ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-bouman-oqhx2

Comment: Okay i played with it and adding `babel/runtime` to dependency resolved it. Export your package with that. Remove your `devDependencies` and add them to `dependencies`

Comment: Can't express my gratitude, my friend. Thank you!!

Comment: Pleasure. Have fun developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your `devDependencies` to `dependencies`. `devDependencies` are not exported in build and that is why maybe your `babel/runtime` is failing.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
```

and then build and try.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without needing to merge your `devDependencies` and `dependencies` is to set up your Codesandbox project in a [Container Environment](https://codesandbox.io/docs/environment). Note that you have to set this before creation — as of writing you **cannot** switch between Container and Client environments *after the fact*.

In addition, if you are going to be importing a project into Codesandbox from Github, it implicitly sets the environment to Client. [To workaround this](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2111#issuecomment-597580065), create a *sandbox.config.json* file at the root of your project with the following contents:

```js
{
  "template": "node"
}
```

Make sure this file exists before import. Creating it after the fact will not work.